# Append to file specific entries of syslog

Tags: bash, syslog

As usual, I can inspect the contents of `syslog` entries in this way:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep myentry
```

I need to append all `myentry` rows to a specific file. Of course just redirecting the output of the command above to the file will not work, because it will append all the rows, even if they were already added last time.

The first solution that comes to mind is to cycle among all the rows in `syslog` until I find the last row of the target file. Then I can append all the following ones. Doing this periodically (i.e. using a cronjob or even easier a timed cycle in bash) should do the trick.

Is there something smarter or more elegant to do the same job?

### EDIT

I add what terdon requested:

Example of my syslog:

```
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc local2.info chat[15782]: CONNECT
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc local2.info chat[15782]:  -- got it
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc user.info myentry[14300]: Ready
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc local2.info chat[15782]: send (^M)
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc user.info myentry[14300]: Init complete
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc daemon.info pppd[14362]: Serial connection established.
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc daemon.info pppd[14362]: Using interface ppp0
```

Example of the existing file I want to append to:

```
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc user.info myentry[14300]: Ready
```

Final output I expect from those two files:

```
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc user.info myentry[14300]: Ready
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc user.info myentry[14300]: Init complete
```

### UPDATE

Ok, it seems I need to be *very* specific with the example, regardless my description. So new examples:

**syslog**

```
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc local2.info chat[15782]: CONNECT
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc local2.info chat[15782]:  -- got it
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc user.info myentry[14300]: Ready
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc local2.info chat[15782]: send (^M)
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc user.info myentry[14300]: Init complete
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc daemon.info pppd[14362]: Serial connection established.
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc user.info myentry[14300]: Start operations
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc daemon.info pppd[14362]: Using interface ppp0
```

**current output**

```
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc user.info myentry[14300]: Init complete
```

**new output**

```
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc user.info myentry[14300]: Init complete
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc user.info myentry[14300]: Start operations
```

It should be clear:

1. if the `output` file is empty, append all the `syslog/myentries` rows
2. if the `output` file is not empty, append all the *next* `syslog/myentries` rows (from the matching one)
3. if the `output` file is not empty and there's no matching, still append all the *next* `syslog/myentries` rows (after the last timestamp)

As said, I'm able to do this using the brute force: cycle all rows, check criteria and append if needed.

I'm looking for an easier solution, like the proposal to split the `syslog` entries automatically, but I didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) an example of your syslog and ii) an example of the existing file you want to append to and iii) the final output you expect from those two files. That way, we can test our solutions and we can be sure we understand what you need.

Comment: Why dont you configure rsyslog to log/duplicate those lines into separate logfile?

Comment: @Fiisch, I have `syslog` from `Busybox v1.29.3` and I didn't find how to specify a separate logfile for my entries. If you can elaborate a bit your answer I think it might be a good solution.

Comment: I see. The "busybox" part is important here. Man page for `busybox-syslogd` explicitly states that `/etc/syslog.conf` is ignored here. Your options thus are: 1) the one you are doing now; 2) write to named pipe instead of a file and have some infinite loop read the other end and save the output; 3) Busybox's syslog can log over the network when using `-R host[:port]` so it is basically like option 2 but saves you the hassle of named pipes. https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/busybox-syslogd/syslogd.8.en.html

Comment: @thanasisp, sorry I don't see a contradiction here. I try with other words: it may happen that the output files contains old logs. When you run the script, the file is not empty but there is no matching (due to the old data) with the current syslog. But if the timestamp is after the last entry it's correct to append.

Comment: OK, that's fine, so (3) is the edge case of (2) when the last row does not exist in the file (or let's say "it was the line number 0"). I believe both answers here handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the last line of the existing target file. And then parse backwards the syslog file with `awk` and some help from `tac`:

```bsh
p=$(tail -n1 output)
tac syslog | awk -v p="$p" '$0 == p{exit} /myentry/' | tac >> output
```

When the last line is found (backwards), `awk` will exit. If not found, or the output was initially empty, it will parse the whole file (I assume there are not empty lines into syslog for the case of initially empty output). Also this way we search into the minimum required lines, so it is expected to perform well for large files.

---

Also keep in your toolbox this simple effective command:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' output > output.tmp && mv output.tmp output
```

that you can run anytime, to fix the target file, preserving the order, if for any reason duplicates managed to pass into there.

Comment: If I'm not wrong with my tests, given a `myentry` line in `output` file, it will copies all the lines, not only the next ones - like the terdon solution does.

Comment: I just tested with your new example and it works as expected. Have you tested that?

Comment: Yes I tested it but at first something was wrong, now it seems to work fine, perhaps it was my fault. I tried to use a variable (like `/$MYENTRY/`) instead of hardcode it but finds nothing. What is the correct syntax here?

Comment: The robust way to pass a shell variable to an awk program is using `-v`. Don't forget quoting. If this variable will be used as the pattern to match, here you are: `awk -v my_var="$MYENTRY" '$0 ~ my_var{print "MATCHING"}' file`. (Just keep in mind that you will never use `$` or `//` inside `awk` for matching a pattern from  variable, you will be using the variable alone)

Comment: Just a note, `~` stands for partial matching (like we grep a line), `==` full, exact match, equality of the two strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++; next}/myentry/ &&  !a[$0]' myentries syslog 
Jan 17 13:03:18 stm32mp1-abc user.info myentry[14300]: Init complete
```

That selects the new matching line, so all you need to do is redirect to the original file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++; next}/myentry/ &&  !a[$0]' myentries syslog >> myentries
```

Comment: I found two caveats: if the target file is empty it copies nothing (instead it should copy all the lines). Then I tried to put inside a valid line, but it copied all of them, not only the next ones.

Comment: @Mark well yes. You wanted to specifically avoid duplicates. There's no point in running this if you don't have duplicates. If the file is empty, just run `grep myentry /var/log/syslog`. I don't understand the second point. Please add an example to your question. I used the data you gave and it worked as expected.